# css sliding content transition

Tags: css, transition, sliding

I am designing a new page for my website and I have had an idea about sliding content in from the right.
In my head this would work by creating separate divs for what would usually be content separated through different pages; i.e. `<div id="home_content">`, `<div ="about_content">` and `<div ="contact_content">`.  Then once a link is clicked, instead of having the new page load, the content in the relevant div will slide in from the right.

I also require that the content divs have a property of 100% width so that it looks right on various resolutions and if a window is re-sized.

Can someone explain how I could achieve this?

Many thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! A better way to ask questions (and get answers) on here is to first [try some things](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). For instance, you want sliding and what is essentially a "one-page" site. Therefore, you can look that up in Google to see how others have done it and try it for yourself. Then, when you get stuck, you can come back with a more specific, technical question.

Comment: Hi.  Thanks for your reply.  I have googled it quite a lot and not found a real solution so I asked this question.  Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!
I think the best practice is using CSS3 `transition` with `width: 100%` and `margin-left`. It makes the transitions very smooth and the only thing you have to do in JS is changing the classes. See the example: http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/jGbhh/

I hope it helps!

Comment: Hey that was really helpful.  Many thanks.  But I would like to get it where the content slides in from either side alternating each time.  Also instead of sliding over the existing content I would like the existing to exit the opposite side of the screen to the content entering the screen, if that makes sense :S

Comment: So if I understand, the boxes have fix position to _each other_. Then it is easier to use a 'big box', and modify it's position with eg. `margin-left`. See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/Stocki/jGbhh/6/.

Comment: Hey @Stocki, I have looked at you 2nd example and its almost what I am after.  However, I have tried to implement your technique but I cant get it to work right.  My fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hJbyq/4/

Where I said almost what I after above, it would be great if the transition happens from home page to the contact page, the about page and any pages in between are not seen.  Also, if you go through the links in order on your example they all come in from the right.  In your example I would like the pages to appear from opposite sides even if the the links are explored in order.  Cheers

Comment: I reversed the `margin-left` 'order', so this example should be good for the original concept: http://jsfiddle.net/jGbhh/9/. However, I modified your jsFiddle, too, so I think you can use it better: http://jsfiddle.net/hJbyq/11/ (PS: Be careful with the heights of `.content` or use `overflow-y: scroll;`)